# Calling function once when user starts typing and stops typing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an input field in React, in this input field the user is typing a message. I want, when the user starts typing, to call a function only once. I tried a solution, but it's calling the function again and again.

```
 export default function App() {
      let typingTimer; //timer identifier
      let doneTypingInterval = 5000; 
      let myInput = document.getElementById("input-text");
    
      //on keyup, start the countdown
      if (myInput) {
        myInput.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
          clearTimeout(typingTimer);
          if (myInput.value) {
            typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
          }
        });
      }
    
      //user is "finished typing," do something
      function doneTyping() {
        console.log("done");
      }
    
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
          
          <form>
            <input type="search" id="input-text" placeholder="Start typing...." />
          </form>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

The above code is calling `doneTyping` after 5 seconds, but five times. I want to call only once, and same when the user stops typing.

Comment: i think its a closure issue since you are working with a callback of event listener make `typingTimer` var from let and try if it fixes your problem

Comment: The OP is looking for a technique called `debounce`. There are libraries for it e.g. the [`debounce` implementation of lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce)

Comment: Peter Seliger : Can you please update the answer how can i use this in my case

Comment: @Mudasir ... Sorry I came up with a working example code, underscore's debounce mixed with your react example code as executable snippet but the question meanwhile got closed, thus I was not able anymore to paste the answer.

Comment: @DrewReese ... I vote for opening this Q again since none of the here provided approaches nor the one that got linked as possible answer do fulfill the OP's request of ... *" I want to call only once [when the user starts typing] and same [the second time] when the user stops typing"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure its a closure issue. This code example works just fine for reset the timer.

```js
let timer;
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', () => {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(callback, 1000);
})

function callback() {
  console.log('called');
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="test" value="click me">
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use something like `Debounce`.

Here's a working example based on your code at [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-hoover-sv2in?file=/src/App.js:0-653).

Note: Do check the console.

```js
import React, { useRef } from "react";

const DEBOUNCE_THRESHOLD = 500;

export default function App() {
  const timeoutHandler = useRef(null);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    if (timeoutHandler.current) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutHandler.current);
    }
    timeoutHandler.current = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(event.target.value);
    }, DEBOUNCE_THRESHOLD);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>

      <form>
        <input
          type="search"
          onChange={handleChange}
          id="input-text"
          placeholder="Start typing...."
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```